# manipulate list of list using random and restrictions

Tags: python, list, random, list-comprehension

I have two lists a and b.

```
a=[[3, 1], [3, 2, 3], [5, 1, 4, 8], [3, 5], [10, 1, 3, 6, 7],[2,1,2]]
b=[[4], [3], [9], [5], [21],[5]]
```

List of list a is interpreted as follows.

- a[0]=[3,1]. This means I want 3 items, where item 1 must be included.
- a[-1]=[2,1,2] I want 2 items, where item 1 and item 2 must
  be included.
- a[2] = [5,1,4,8] I want 5 items, where item 1, item 4 and item 8 must be included.

List of list b is the available list of item from which list a can take from.

- b[0]=[4] this means item 1, item 2, item 3 and item 4 is available. This is linked
  to a[0]
- b[-1]=[5] item 1, item 2, item 3, item 4 and item 5 is available. This is linked to a[-1]
- b[2]=[9] this means i have 9 items is available. This is linked to a[2]

I'm trying to create a new list of list c such that it produces the following result.

For a[0]=[3,1] and b[0]=[4] it should produce the following result [1,2,4]

For a[-1]=[2,1,2] and b[-1]=[5] it should produce [1,2]

For a[2] = [5,1,4,8] and  b[2]=[9] should produce [1,4,8,3,9]

What I have tried so far:

```
import random

a=[[3, 1], [3, 2, 3], [5, 1, 4, 8], [3, 5], [10, 1, 3, 6, 7],[2,1,2]]

b=[[4], [3], [9], [5], [21],[5]]

c=[sorted(random.sample(range(1, j[0]+1), int(i[0]))) for i,j in zip(a,b)]

print(c) # produces [[1, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 4, 6, 9], [1, 4, 5], [2, 5, 6, 7, 13, 15, 16, 19, 20, 21], [3, 4]]

As you can see, list c does not take into account those restrictions that I need.
```

Desired output will look something like this.

```
c= [[1,2,4],[2,3,1],[1,4,8,3,9],[5,1,3],[1,3,6,7,2,5,9,10,20,21],[1,2]]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "item 1" and "item 2", etc.? My initial thought was that the `b` list is what the "items" are, but your explanation of `b` doesn't align with that. Could you clarify?

Comment: Why is `c[0]` not `[1,2,3]` and `c[2]` not `[1,4,8,2,3]`?

Comment: items are just numbers 1,2,3 etc. c[0] can be [1,2,3] as long as 1 is inside the list, the other 2 numbers (or what ever remaining) can be what ever random numbers.

Comment: @Aggrahoth, the b list is the available items you have at your disposal. For example consider the first element of each list in a and b. [3, 1] and [4].

[4] means i have [1,2,3,4] but [3,1] tells me to create a list of 3 elements where 1 must be included hence i can have [1,2,3] or [1,3,4] or [1,2,4]. As you can see the other two numbers can be random so i don't care as long as the 1 is included.

Comment: right so its a list from 1 to the number in the `b` array?

Comment: For each a[i] and b[i] create a list or set of available items as defined by b[i]. Then remove the items required by a[i] from available items and add them to the result list. Finally `sample` the remaining number (if >0) of requested items from the list of available items and add them to result list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a loop over the two lists and construct a `remaining_items` list to randomly sample from -

```py
 c = []
 for constraints, items in zip(a, b):
    num_items, *required_items = constraints
    pick_list = list(_ for _ in range(1, items[0] + 1) if _ not in required_items)
    num_items_to_pick = num_items - len(required_items)
    remaining_items = random.sample(pick_list, num_items_to_pick)
    print(required_items + remaining_items)
    c.append(required_items + remaining_items)
```

**Output**

```
[[1, 2, 3],
 [2, 3, 1],
 [1, 4, 8, 3, 6],
 [5, 3, 1],
 [1, 3, 6, 7, 18, 2, 14, 21, 19, 15],
 [1, 2]]
```